# java nextFloat exception

Tags: java, исключения, scanner

Помогите понять почему nextFloat() выводит exception когда пишу 1.1?

```java
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter N: ");
            float n = scan.nextFloat();

        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an double integer!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вводите вы что?)

Comment: @pavel например 1.1

Comment: Надо вводить в зависимости от локали. Десятичная точка или `.` или `,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> почему nextFloat() выводит exception когда пишу 1.1?

Скорее всего потому что при русской локали надо вводить `1,1`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Main {

    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.print("Enter N: ");
            Float n = Float.valueof(scan.nextFloat());

        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter an double integer!");
        }
    }
}
```